# Control AllowToAddGuests value on Microsoft Teams Unified Group

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to control Guest Access on Teams on a Unified Group Level.

I tried to follow this article but it seems that some variables (`$SettingID`, for example) don't get a value:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/Allow-or-Block-Guest-Users-from-a-Specific-Team-in-Microsoft/td-p/175918

```
import-module azureadpreview
connect-azuread

$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

$GroupID = get-unifiedgroup -Identity <smtpaddress> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExternalDirectoryObjectId
$SettingID = Get-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectID $GroupID | select-object -expandproperty ID
remove-azureadobjectsetting -id $settingid -targettype Groups -TargetObjectID $GroupID
$template = Get-AzureADDirectorySettingTemplate | ? {$_.displayname -eq "group.unified.guest"}
$settingsCopy = $template.CreateDirectorySetting()
$settingsCopy["AllowToAddGuests"]=$False
New-AzureADObjectSetting -TargetType Groups -TargetObjectId $groupID -DirectorySetting $settingsCopy
```

From what i see the script fails from the `$settingsid` line on. This variable gives me a Null value result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue came from the AzureAD module, the setting is only available on AzureADPreview.